# Zeusminer Blizzards no longer working with bfgminer 5.0.0

Tags: asic, scrypt, bfgminer, raspberry-pi

I was mining off a raspberry pi with some zeus blizzards, I've had to format the SD because it got corrupted and so I took the chance to install the latest bfgminer.

the raspberry is running raspbian and I've installed bfgminer following [this install guide on BitcoinTalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=121253.0).

```
sudo ./bfgminer -d? -D
```

or

```
sudo ./bfgminer -S zeusminer:all -d? -D
```

prints out

```
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] setrlimit: Soft fd limit not being changed from 1024 (FD_SETSIZE=1024; hard limit=4096)
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] Started bfgminer 5.0.0
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] lowlevel_scan: Found vcom device at dev_t:01bc000000000000 (path=/dev/ttyUSB1, vid=0000, pid=0000, manuf=Silicon Labs, prod=CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller, serial=0001)
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] lowlevel_scan: Found vcom device at dev_t:00bc000000000000 (path=/dev/ttyUSB0, vid=0000, pid=0000, manuf=Silicon Labs, prod=CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller, serial=0001)
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] Devices detected:
[2015-01-15 18:01:27] Timers: Using clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)
0 devices listed
```

and

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

so the blizzards are connected indeed to /dev/ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1 but bfgminer doens't not recognize them. Should I add something in the install procedure to enable the zeusminers? They were working until a couple of days ago before the SD formatting procedure.

Comment: Weird - most of the bfgminer printouts with zeusminer blizzard say 'Found usb device' not 'Found vcom device.' I can't figure out what triggers that.